# flutter CheckboxListTile loses checked state when scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to use CheckboxListTile in a popup widget so the user can check as many items as needed and then click OK to accept the checked items which adds them to a list of items in main widget

What happens is CheckboxListTile loses checked state when scrolling down for some items, when getting back up in the list it is not checked anymore,

here is my code for the CheckboxListTile

```
class ItemTileWithImage extends StatefulWidget {
      final Model model;
      ItemTileWithImage(this.model);
      @override
      _ItemTileWithImageState createState() => _ItemTileWithImageState();
    }
    
    class _ItemTileWithImageState extends State<ItemTileWithImage> {
      bool _checked = false;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Color hintColor = Theme.of(context).hintColor;
        Color primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
        return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
          height: 85,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(color: hintColor, width: 0.5),
            ),
          ),
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            activeColor: primaryColor,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            value: _checked,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _checked = val;
              });
              if (val) {
                Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .insertModelItems(widget.model.code);
              } else {
                Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .removeModelItems(widget.model.remoteId);
              }
            },
            secondary: widget.model.imageUrl != null
                ? CachedNetworkImage(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 60,
                    imageUrl: widget.model.imageUrl,
                    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          height: 30,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            value: downloadProgress.progress,
                            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  )
                : Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/mini_logo.png',
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
            title: Text(widget.model.code ?? '${widget.model.barCode}'),
            subtitle: Text(
              widget.model.name ?? '',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: try like this `setState(() {_checked = !_checked;});` rest of your code same

Comment: it changed correctly on screen, so the state is changing properly, which means it is not a matter of checked=val or = !checked

Answer (score 0):

Flutter apps typically 'clean up' your off screen state. Some off-screen widgets will experience the loss of certain view related attributes. This is discussed some in the `Keys` section [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro#keys). You can instantiate stateless widgets in a way where their variable attributes are stored off for later recall.

Here is a demo utilizing rows of CheckboxListTile widgets which keep their state even with scrolling/going off-screen. You can use a DartPad of the below code [here](https://dartpad.dev/6e5b742de3123f3a901ba559d40e2fd5).

```
// Remember CheckboxListTile status with scrolling demo.
// Currently utilizes rows in implementation.
// This can be cut down to maintain a single checkbox list tile.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  // Refresh Callback for descendant widgets (if checkboxes are generated in seperate widget)
  refresh() {setState(() {});}
  // Rows with checkbox title and check value
  // Must update second value in entry to maintain check status while scrolling
  List<List> rowData = [
    ['row1', true], ['row2', false], ['row3', false],
    ['row4', false], ['row5', false], ['row6', false],
    ['row7', false], ['row8', false], ['row9', false],
    ['row10', false], ['row11', false], ['row12', false],
    ['row13', false], ['row14', false], ['row15', false],
    ['row16', false], ['row17', false], ['row18', false],
    ['row19', false], ['row20', false], ['row21', false],
    ['row22', false], ['row23', false], ['row24', false]];
  List<Row> rows = []; // Holds row objects generated from rowData (with checkboxes)
  int row = 0;
  int rowCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    rows = []; // Refresh rows
    for (int i=0; i<rowData.length; i++) { // Init/refresh row widgets
      rows.add(Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded (
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              value: rowData[i][1] as bool, // Check value
              title: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Text(rowData[i][0], style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50))
              ), // Title for check box
              checkColor: Colors.black,
              dense: false,
              onChanged: (newValue) { // On click of check box
                setState(() {
                  print("Checkbox clicked");
                  rowData[i][1] = newValue; // Update value in the RowData list
                });
              }
            ),
          )
        ]
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Remember Checkboxes Demo'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff66b366),
        ),
        body: Column (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[for (var i in rows) i,] // Fill in rows
                ),
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Abstracting the idea for the question's implementation, you can replace your `_checked` variable to be a passed in boolean from the parent of the `ItemTileWithImage` widget. Also, you would want to pass in a function, like the `refresh()` function in the demo, to call in the onChange block after updating your shared check value. This allows you to refresh the state of your parent widget to include the updated check status.

Note: I am a relative novice with Flutter so apologies if this solution is considered bad practice.

The above implementation was developed with Flutter 2.5.3 and Dart 2.14.4.